# Keep postgres's docker container running instead of started

Tags: postgresql, docker

Here there is my configuration. A piece of configuration actually. I've standard things. The same I usually use with mysql.

```
postgres:
  build:
    context: ./docker/postgres
  container_name: 'acme-postgres'
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - ./docker/postgres/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:cached
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=acme
    - POSTGRES_USER=acme
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=acme
  networks:
    - acme-network
```

All works:

```
docker-compose up -d postgres
[+] Running 1/1
⠿ Container geco-postgres  Started
```

But not in the way I expected. In fact, the container is Starded and not running. The dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM postgres:latest
```

Maybe something is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `restart: 'always'` option to postgres's configuration:

```
postgres:
  restart: 'always'
  build:
    context: ./docker/postgres
  container_name: 'acme-postgres'
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - ./docker/postgres/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:cached
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=acme
    - POSTGRES_USER=acme
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=acme
  networks:
    - acme-network
```